# When should I use conformsToProtocol and respondsToSelector methods?

Tags: ios, objective-c-protocol

What is the use of conformsToProtocol and respondsToSelector method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`conformsToProtocol` method let you check is your object implement specific protocol. 
It doesn't tell you has it contains the method this protocol defines (some of the method can be optional).

`respondsToSelector` check is your object has a specific method (the method doesn't need to be defined in any protocol) it can be method defined in class.

Comment: CDMProtocol *aRef = [[CDMProtocol alloc]init];
             aRef.aDelegate = self;
             [aRef validate];

Comment: CDMProtocol *aRef = [[CDMProtocol alloc]init];
    aRef.aDelegate = self;
    [aRef validate];
    
I am setting only delegate but not adding in interface @interface CDMViewController : UIViewController<CDMProtocol> then why conformsToProtocol giving false?

Comment: Because you need to add <CDMProtocol> to CDMProtocol if you want it to conform to this protocol. You should have a complier warning if you set delegate to self but not implement to the protocol(<...>) unless you have just optional methods.

Answer (score 1):

They perform similar functionality in checking if a class implements certain methods, but I guess you could see `conformsToProtocol` as short-cut to calling `respondsToSelector` multiple times on the object.

`respondsToSelector` is more fine-grained and I have never even used `conformsToProtocol`, preferring to use `respondsToSelector` to test for delegate methods before calling them.

Answer (score 0):

`respondtoselector` will check for method existence in the confirmed protocol instances.